# Write Git commit message in different editor than default

Tags: bash, git

I'd like to be able to occasionally use a different editor when writing commit messages.  I've found plenty of answers on how to change the default editor, but I don't want to change that - VIM is normally fine.  What I'd like is some option like `git commit --editor=<editor_name>` where `<editor_name>` is the editor I want to use when writing the commit message for **that commit only.**

The only thing I've found that is similar to what I'd like is opening a new file with `<editor_name> <newcommitfilename>`, write message, save and close file, then use `git commit -F <newcommitfilename>`.
Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What about 2 bash aliases? One to change your editor to X, and one to change it to nano? Then you can quickly change whenever you'd like with one command before you commit.

Comment: How about this? `export GIT_EDITOR='nano' && git commit && unset GIT_EDITOR`.

Comment: Simpler than the suggestion by qrsngky, but similar in spirit: Just do a `GIT_EDITOR=nano git commit`, and you then don't need to _unset_ afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Git commands use the form:

```
git <verb>
```

You may insert options before the verb, e.g.,

```
git -c core.pager=cat show
```

The `-c` option in particular takes a configuration item name, such as `core.pager`, `core.editor`, `user.name`, and so on, and a value, joined with an equals sign `=` like this.

Since your goal is to use a particular editor, `git -c core.editor=whatever commit` does the trick.

As several commenters noted, there are other ways to do this.  For the editor in particular, the environment variable `$GIT_EDITOR` overrides `core.editor`, so:

```
GIT_EDITOR=nano git commit
```

runs `git commit` with `GIT_EDTIOR` set to `nano` for the duration of the one command (assuming POSIX-style shell).